# linux fine tuning after setting the MTU to jumbo frame

Tags: linux, redhat, linux-networking, ifconfig, mtu

We want to set the MTU to 9000 bytes on our Linux machines (distribution is Redhat 7)

In this case, how would I tune the memory page size according to MTU size of 9000 bytes?

Also, what are the risks associated with setting the MTU to 9000 Bytes? Could there be performance issues? And what could be the possible impact on network performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing special in memory configuration is needed, jumbo framed should work in standard configuration. Sure your network card (and driver's) should support it. Also not all switches support jumbo frames. Read https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/jumbo_frames

Comment: Jumbo frames will work, but the question is would memory page size tuning enhance the operation.

Comment: Memory page size is dictated by CPU architecture and not your choice. For Intel you have a choice of 2 sizes either 4KB (which is standard page size) or 4MB (which is known as HugePage). Huge pages may have negative effect, so I would not generally recommend it. This mode is good for database server, but not for, say, 'php'-worker server. Most NICs work directly with DMA controller and have internal buffer of enough size for jumbo page buffering. DMA transfer speed doesn't depend on page size, so  I don't think that adjusting page size would have any effect on network operations.

Comment: so I want to summary your last note - we not see any correlation between the MTU size and the memory page size - is this right ?